# Reify random lookup value so it stays the same each time it is used

Tags: ansible

If I have this var defined in my playbook:

```
vars:

- random_ref: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digits') | to_uuid }}"
```

then whenever I use `{{ random_ref}}` else where in the playbook it generates a new random string each time. I want to generate it once, and then be able to reference it elsewhere.

I need to 'pass by value' and not 'pass by reference', so to speak. How can I reify it so it stays the same on each time I use it?

Comment: Once you generate it as above, you can use the variable anywhere in the playbook, the value doesnt change. Is it getting changed for you? Can you show an example?

Comment: If it is for multiple times while running playbook, you can use set_fact and  run_once: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as below

```
- name: Test
  set_fact:
   random_ref: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters,digits') | to_uuid }}"
  run_once: true
```